# Ocurrió un error al actualizar las entradas

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hola solicito de su ayuda.

Estoy empezando con entity framework y estoy realizando un sistema, tengo una relación creada con Code First pero al momento de ingresar los datos me sale el error de que el nombre de mi columna no es el correcto. Les adjunto el codigo y algunas imagenes para que vean el error.

Tabla Client

```
 public class ClientEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^(?!0+$)(\\+\\d{1,3}[- ]?)?(?!0+$)\\d{10,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone no.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Ocupation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AppId { get; set; }
}
```

Tabla MedicalHistory

```
public class MedicalHistoryEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int MedicalHistoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ClientEntity ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

La relación en mi BD se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi código que uso para insertar en las dos tablas.

```
public async Task<GeneralResponse> Create(CreateClientViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Clients --- Create --- Start request to create identifiers.");
            var client = new ClientEntity
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Age = model.Age,
                Address = model.Address,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                Gender = model.Gender,
                Ocupation = model.Ocupation,
                AppId = model.AppId
            };
            _context.Add(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var medicalHistory = new MedicalHistoryEntity
            {
                Place = model.MedicalHistory.Place,
                DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(model.MedicalHistory.DateTime),
                ClientId = client
            };
            _context.Add(medicalHistory);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
            return new GeneralResponse
            {
                Status = true,
                Code = 200,
                Message = "The record was created successfully."
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Clients --- Create --- Error: {(ex?.InnerException?.Message) ?? ex.Message}.");
            return new GeneralResponse
            {
                Status = false,
                Code = 500,
                Message = (ex?.InnerException?.Message) ?? ex.Message
            };
        }
    }
```

Pero al querer insertar me da el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.
De ante mano les agradezco.

Saludos.